# AngularJS directives: Substituting attribute values directly into template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I've been trying to develop an AngularJS directive that outputs a labelled form-field.

I'd like to be able to use a tag like the following:

```
<simpleTextField bind="user.email" label="Email" name="email" 
                 placeholder="Enter email address"></simpleTextField>
```

This is to produce the following (bootstrap) HTML output:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" 
           ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Enter email address">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the attributes include both an attribute that defines a binding and one whose value is to be substituted directly into the template HTML.

I'd like it to be properly encapsulated.  In other words, I don't want to have to modify the view's controller in order to accommodate usage of this directive.

None of the examples I've seen satisfy my requirements because (1) they don't substitute the attribute values directly into the template, and/or (2) they rely on the controller of the view in which the directive is being used to be modified.

Please note that I'm new to AngularJS so I may be completely off track here.

Comment: I've tried using the basic approach that CaspNZ suggested below, but I could never get it to behave.  For example, it would only substitute the first two variables (which seemed completely bizarre) and then I noticed that it seemed to interfere with the rest of the controls on the form somehow.  I'm not sure if it mangled the scope or something.  When I tried CaspNZ's code below, it completely removed everything else on the form.

Comment: Actually there was a type in CaspNZ's code (incorrect end-tag).  When I fixed that it worked fine.

Comment: CaspNZ has now fixed the typo so it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have made something that should work.
You can pass in values to directly bind to the template and the directive has no knowledge of the parent's model. 
The HTML + directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label>Parent Scope Email:{{email}}</label></br>
    <simple-text-field simple-bind-to="email" simple-label="Email" simple-name="email" 
             simple-placeholder="Enter email address" simple-dynamic-scope="user.email">
    </simple-text-field>
</div>
```

The directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('simpleTextField', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            simpleBindTo: "=",
            simpleLabel: "@simpleLabel",
            simpleName: "@simpleName",
            simplePlaceholder: "@simplePlaceholder",
        },
        template: '<div class="form-group">' +
        '  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="{{simpleName}}">{{simpleLabel}}</label>' +
        '  <div class="col-sm-10">' +
        '    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{simpleName}}" ' +
        '        placeholder="{{simplePlaceholder}}" ng-model="simpleBindTo" >' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.email = '';
});
```

By using the '=' access modifier, the ng-model can be assigned variable member of the parent scope, without the directive knowing anything about this variable.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/kU38K/5/) is a jsfiddle for the above example.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried it and it rendered the control but nothing after the control.  For example, I just put the text, 'Hello' on the next line and it didn't show up.

Comment: Oh, it was just a problem with the end-tag in your HTML.  It should be </simple-text-field> rather than </simpleTextField>.  After I noticed that it worked fine.  Thanks again!